# String Array compare with dataset values in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have following code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("RetriveData",
             new SqlParameter("@Field", "mark1"),
             new SqlParameter("@TblNm", "stud"),
             new SqlParameter("@WhereClause", "where id=124"));
```

with this I am getting below values:

```
Id   mark1
124     21 
124     31
124     41 
124     23
124     35
124     56
124     67
124     54
124     45
124     63
```

Now from below I am getting students mark:

```
DataSet dsmark = new DataSet();
dsmark = cls.ReturnDataSet("RetriveData",
                 new SqlParameter("@Field", "marks"),
                 new SqlParameter("@TblNm", "student"),
                 new SqlParameter("@WhereClause", "where id=124"));
```

From above query I am getting the below output:

```
Id    marks
124    63
```

Below code for comparison:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["mark1"].ToString() != dsmark .Tables[0].Rows[0]["marks"].ToString())
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('err')", true);
            }
           else
            {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('No err')", true);
            }
        }
```

But when i do this it will compare the values but when every time if condition call and it is not satisfy then it will give me message "err".

But that "63" values in the database..

```
so i want like it will check with the all values and then if that values is not match then and then only give me message "err".
```

Comment: `new SqlParameter("@WhereClause", "where id=124 and mark1 = 63")`?

Comment: What `ReturnDataSet` do exactly?

Comment: Well, why don't just iterate over your first set of values and compare with your second value?

Comment: returndata set is a function which execute the storedprocedure and returns values.  i want to compare that 63 value with that 10 different values and if it is not equal then it gives error messgae.

Comment: Compare in what way? you want rows which are `equal`? or `greater`? or `lesser`?

Comment: those 10 values of array with this single value. if it is not equal then gives error

Comment: Your first set is not array. It is `DataTable`, I suppose.

Comment: You can use `foreach` and loop through all rows from `ds` and compare with your mark.

Comment: `dsmark` contain only one row?

Comment: yes it contains 1 row.

Comment: i have update the output of dsmark

Comment: There are 3 rows? and you want only `63` from it?

Comment: I want to compare that all 3 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are stored in [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside of `DataSet`. So you can iterate first set as

```
foreach(DataRow dro in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   // your comparison logic here
}
```

and compare values of column `mark1` of that table with `dsMark.Tables[0].Rows[0]["marks"]` (or any other comparison you need)

**UPDATE**

Based on updated question - your comparison logic is incorrect. To achieve your goals it should be something like:

```
bool matchFound = false;

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["mark1"].ToString() == dsmark .Tables[0].Rows[0]["marks"].ToString())
        matchFound = true;
}

if (matchFound)
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('No err')", true);
else
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('err')", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code,

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   //your code to compare.
}
```

Comment: Yes, but logic will change, one value may equal to one in `ds` but may not be equal to another.

Comment: comparing for `not equal` will give all as not equal if you have different values in `dsmark`.