# How to compare two DataSet columns values in C#?

Tags: c#

In below code i want to compare two dataset column's values but its not match then also getting true this condition.so how to really compare?

```
if (dsEmp.Tables[0].Columns["EmpName"].ToString() == dsAllTables.Tables[2].Columns["EmpName"].ToString())
{

}
```

Comment: Have you looked in debug mode? you are comaring the strings correctly, I don't see a problem in the code itself.

Comment: We have no idea what the data is... it would *really* help if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It's also not clear what you mean by "but its not match then also getting true this condition".

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27637300/4513879

Comment: Dhaval nailed it, I think. The OP is comparing the ToString() of the columns, not of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing two column-names, so `"EmpName"` with `"EmpName"` which is always true. `Tables[0].Columns["EmpName"]` returns a `DataColumn` with that name and `ToString` returns the name of the column which is `"EmpName"`. So that's pointless.

If you instead want to know if two tables contain the same `EmpName` value in one of their rows you can use LINQ:

```
var empRowsEmpName = dsEmp.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("EmpName"));
var allRowsEmpName = dsAllTables.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("EmpName"));
IEnumerable<string> allIntersectingEmpNames = empRowsEmpName.Intersect(allRowsEmpName);
if (allIntersectingEmpNames.Any())
{

}
```

Now you even know which `EmpName` values are contained in both tables. You could use a `foreach`-loop:

```
foreach(string empName in allIntersectingEmpNames)
    Console.WriteLine(empName);
```

If you want to find out if a specific value is contained in both:

```
bool containsName = allIntersectingEmpNames.Contains("SampleName");
```

If you just want to get the first matching:

```
string firstIntersectingEmpName = allIntersectingEmpNames.FirstOrDefault(); 
if(firstIntersectingEmpName != null){ 
    //  yes, there was at least one EmpName that was in both tables
}
```

Comment: woww its great working..many many thanq M.r Tim Schmelter. but this is for both are equal condition then how to take not equal condition?

Comment: @dawoodabbas: so all `EmpName` which are in the first table but not in the second? You can use `empRowsEmpName.Except(allRowsEmpName)` or vice versa.

Comment: Error 52 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Comment: like above thrwoing an error if i took except methode

Comment: I want to compare if any name will get in empRowsEmpName with compareing to allRowsEmpName then leave if state ment.so how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single row, this should work:

```
if (dsEmp.Tables[0].Row[0]["EmpName"].ToString() == dsAllTables.Tables[2].rows[0]["EmpName"].ToString())
{

}
```

For multiple rows you have to iterate through table:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dsEmp.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= dsAllTables.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        if (dsEmp.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EmpName"].ToString() == dsAllTables.Tables[2].Rows[j]["EmpName"].ToString())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tim's answer is better, but you still get to keep my upvote for being the first that realized what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I have two datatables - dtbl and mtbl, and I use this to return records that have a difference, as another `DataTable.`

```
    //compare the two datatables and output any differences into a new datatable, to return
    var differences = dtbl.AsEnumerable().Except(mtbl.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
    return differences.Any() ? differences.CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();
```